# Internal hyperlink to "Jump to 'Today'"

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that was in Excel, but is now in Google Sheets. It had a HYPERLINK formula that would jump to the row with today's date in Column B (handy for daily logging of information). The formula was:

```
=HYPERLINK("#A"&MATCH("TODAY",A3:A629,0)+3&":A"&MATCH("TODAY",A3:A629,0)+3,"Jump to today")
```

It worked by looking for the cell in Column A containing `TODAY`, which is driven by an IF formula based on the date in column B. That HYPERLINK functionality doesn't work in Google Sheets.

Is there a way to fix it, or another way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=HYPERLINK("l i n k&range=B"&MATCH("TODAY",A1:A629,0),"Jump to today")
```

where `l i n k` is the full URL. Be careful with the quotes.